# check "newness" / "is-read" of /var/spool/mail/$USER like pam_mail for custom motd script

Tags: pam, mailx, motd

How can I check with `bash` or `python` (preferred) if there are some `unread` mails in `/var/spool/mail/$USER` like `pam_mail` does?

I'd like to use this for my own custom [motd script, `motd.dynamic`](https://github.com/Centril/motd.dynamic/)

Comment: this can be done with `find`, if that is helpful for you? Do you want to specify a *time* to say 'show me files that are more recently modified/accessed than x' or a *file* to say 'show me files that are more recently modified/accessed than file x', and is it the accessed or modified time that you are concerned about?

Comment: Yeah, it helps! Can always use https://docs.python.org/2/library/stat.html in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to determine whether there are unread mails in a mailbox file is traditionally to check if the access time is earlier than the modification time.

You can easily find these times using the `stat` command; by specifying a custom output format these values can be imported into the shell:

```
eval $(stat -c 'atime=%X; mtime=%Y' /var/spool/mail/$USER)
```

After that you can compare these values:

```
if [ $atime -le $mtime ]; then echo 'You have new mail'; fi
```

To make it a bit more robust, check the existence of the mail file first.

Comment: Ah, the access time - thanks! If I want to check the newness of a specific mail in an mbox setting - should I check the `Received: by centrilnas (Postfix, from userid 0) id 518741656A; Tue,  3 Mar 2015 13:33:09 +0100 (CET)` or `Date: Tue,  3 Mar 2015 13:33:09 +0100 (CET)` field in the file against the access time?

Comment: I have a Delivery-date: header which is added by my MTA (exim) when the mail is actually written. You may also have a first line "From " (with a space after the "From"), the date there should also be the moment it was written to the mbox. Received: headers are added when received by the MTAs en route so have nothing to do with when it was written to your mbox.

Answer (score 0):

I took the idea that @wurtel gave me and made it into python:

```
def mail():
    # See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4155
    import os
    import os.path
    import time
    mailbox = '/var/spool/mail/' + curr_user()

    def d( content, color = COLOR_NORMAL ):
        return colored( justify( content, 1 ) + '\n', color )

    def none():
        return d( 'No new mail' ) if MAIL_NONE_DISPLAY else ''

    if not os.path.isfile( mailbox ): return none()

    stat = os.stat( mailbox )
    if stat.st_mtime > stat.st_atime:
        # mailbox has been modified after accessed.
        if MAIL_NEW_COUNT:
            # check how many new mails.
            count = 0
            newlines = 2

            for l in open( mailbox ):
                if l.isspace(): newlines += 1
                else:
                    # New == We have a From header the date > atime.
                    if newlines == 2 and l.startswith( 'From ' ) and time.mktime( time.strptime( l.split( None, 2 )[2].strip() ) ):
                        count += 1
                    newlines = 0

            # open() will change access time, correct it.
            os.utime( mailbox, (time.time(), stat.st_mtime) if MAIL_CONSIDER_READ else (stat.st_atime, stat.st_mtime) )

            return d( 'You have {0} new mails'.format( count ), COLOR_WARN ) if count else none()
        else: return d( 'You have new mail', COLOR_WARN )
    else: return none()
```